# php merge json arrays into one array

Tags: php, arrays, json, file, merge

I am trying to loop through some json files, and combine them into one json file. My plan is to have a global `$allData` array, and just merge new candidates into them.

```
<?php
$allData = array();
$count = 0;
if ($handle = opendir('./json/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

            echo $entry."<br />";

            $source_file = file_get_contents('./json/'.$entry);

            $data = json_decode($source_file,TRUE);

            if($data != null){


                $allData = array_merge($allData,$data);
                echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /> !!!! <br /><br /><br /><br />";
                print_r($allData);

            }
            else{
                echo "Invalid Json File";
            } //end else            
        }
closedir($handle);
}

echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /> !!!! <br /><br /><br /><br />";

print_r($allData);
```

However, the merge is overwriting the file. How can I combine multiple json files into one?

I would like the following result:

1.json:

```
{"date":"10"},{"comment":"some comment"},{"user":"john"}
```

2.json:

```
{"date":"11"},{"comment":"another quote"},{"comment":"jim"}
```

combined.json

```
[{"date":"10"},{"comment":"some comment"},{"user":"john"},
{"date":"11"},{"comment":"another quote"},{"comment":"jim"}]
```

I am only getting one of these values after I merge the arrays.

```
[{"date":"25.4.2013 10:40:10"},{"comment":"some text"},{"comment":"some more text"},
[{"date":"25.4.2013 10:45:15"},{"comment":"another quote"},{"comment":"quote"}]]
```

Comment: Have you tryed using array_merge() with json_decode()'ed data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your merge is odd:

```
$result = array_merge($allData,$data);
```

You want to be merging each new `$data` array onto a growing `$allData` array right? I think you want to do this instead:

```
$allData = array_merge($allData,$data);
```

Also you can get rid of this, it's not necessary.

```
if($count == 0){
    $allData = $data;
}
```

Comment: I have logic so I don't overwrite it. And $allData is already declared above.

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c See my updated answer. I think `$result` is complicating things, and you don't need it. Merge `$data` with `$allData` and set it as the new `$allData` each time in your loop.

Comment: I have pursued this, and I still do not get the desired result. It is still getting overwritten.

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c It won't get overwritten if you do it just like I suggested. Feel free to update your question and show your code attempt with this merge if you have issues with it, and I can help show you what's wrong.

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c Here is a really simple example of how your two JSON strings will merge quite nicely: http://3v4l.org/p1bVL. Give me a simple code example of how it's failing for you, and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @jsznobody Found out what my problem was. Didn't have the `[ ]` on all the json files, so it was decoding error I believe. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

As stated before, `$result = array_merge($allData,$data);` is the best way to merge arrays. This code works to merge the two, however, the problem was that my json was not properly formed.

I didn't have `[]` around my two files, so they could not be merged properly.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a bad one but it works: I replace the } of string one with a comma, remove the { of the second string and concatenate those two strings...